# How to design a container like iOS app that can grow in functions?

Tags: ios

We have a requirement where we need to build an iOS app 'A' that would have menu options for a number of functionalities and these functionalities will grow over time. So, the clients suggested that we do an iOS app 'A' that displays just the menu options and the options when clicked will each launch another iOS app (which implements that functionality) residing on the device. This would be a bad user experience considering the user will have to be moved out of 'A' for each link. At the same time, we cannot build all the features in 'A' since the size of 'A' would get too large. 
Is there an elegant design solution for this kind of an application?

Comment: You can build a container project that includes a number of static libraries to support all your different functions.  That doesn't solve your "too large" problem, but it could be as modular as you would like it to be.

Comment: Tell your client that his suggestion will never, ever make it through the App Store review process. Which is probably just the truth. But "evil Apple won't accept your ingenious design" is a much better argument than "stoopid developer refuses to implement your ingenious design, he or she is probably just too stupid or lazy to do it". And how big do you think that app will be? I ported a few hundred thousand lines of code from MacOS X to iOS, and size wasn't really a problem.

Comment: @gnasher729:  I don't think Apple would reject it on that basis.  There are other apps up there that do that sort of thing, and there are legitimate reasons for doing it - sometimes.

Comment: @Jeff- Thanks. Do you know of other apps implementing similar design? We were also concerned that it may get rejected if it only has links and no other functionalities.

Comment: @gnasher729 - I do not know yet how many functions would be added to the app over time. One of the functionality already exists as an independent iOS app and its binary is roughly 22 Mb. So, it won't be possible to include it as a static library or a functionality in the app itself as there would be more functionalities like that coming in and I can only imagine the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching a different app for each function seems a bit clunky at first, but on the other hand it does offer the flexibility of adding additional modules without having to rebuild and redistribute your application every time.  If the modules are independent enough that a user wouldn't need to constantly switch between them, this might not be a bad solution.

You could use [custom URL schemes](http://help.contrast.co/hc/en-us/articles/200865293-URL-Scheme-Intro-for-App-Developers) to launch each module, and use (for example) an XML file to configure which modules are available and the URL scheme to launch each one.  That way you could update the XML file remotely (have the application call a web service on startup to check for an updated configuration file).  Your configuration file could be as simple as something like this:

```
<modules>
    <module name="Module A" url="moduleA://myModuleA"/>
    <module name="Module B" url="moduleB://myModuleB"/>
    <module name="Module C" url="moduleC://myModuleC"/>
</modules>
```

and then the app could provide a button to launch each module.  You can add additional tags for any other information you need about each module (e.g. an icon image or whatever).

When you add a new module, update the config file on the server and the app will find it on the next startup.  Your app would have to redirect the user to the app store to download and install the new module if it's not already installed on their device.

Of course if your modules need to communicate with each other or share data, it gets more complicated.  You can pass parameters between modules in the custom URL scheme, but if they need to share large amounts of data (like a database or something), then you'd need some other way to share that data.

Hope this helps.